# Android Compose doesn't work with KSP, ROOM for multi-module projects

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-symbol-processing, android-compose

I noticed after enabling Android Compose for the project:

```
buildFeatures {
  compose true
}
```

KSP with ROOM doesn't work properly finishing with exceptions like this during bulding project:

```
[ksp] [MissingType]: Element 'pl.softfly.multi_module_room.entity.Card' references a type that is not present - pl.softfly.multi_module_room.entity.Card
```

The problem occurs when the project is multi-module,
ROOM from the module cannot to find ROOM classes from the parent project. If `compose true` is removed everything works as it should.

The project with Android Compose enabled (with exception):
https://github.com/softfly/MultiModuleRoom/commit/de3f6bbd97cee282cf6f329c259dbcd6b6742666

The project with Android Compose disabled (works):
https://github.com/softfly/MultiModuleRoom/commit/a5ce616bedfa438428b0ab1ce450e5eeee680474

Has anyone had a similar problem and was able to solve it?

Comment: Here is solution: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/295909826

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues:

You have the module dependencies backwards - the `app` module should have

```
implementation project(":roommodule")
```

and `roommodule` shouldn't reference the `app` module.

You should also place all of the room entities/daos/database declarations inside the `roommodule`. The `app` module should not have the room dependencies nor the KSP setup.

I didn't look closer into the code, but I fixing the above will give a clean separation between room/compose, and I suspect will fix at least this issue.